# Best practice to monitor docker volume available space

Tags: docker, monitoring, docker-volume

What is the best way/tool to monitor an EBS volume available space when mounted inside a Docker container?

I really need to monitor the available disk space in order to prevent crash because of no `space left on device`.

Do you know of any tool that can monitor that, like datadog, newrelic grafana, prometheus or something opensource?

Answer (score 0):

The telegraf/influxdb/grafana stack can monitor space left on disc. Kapacitor can also be added if you want alerts. If you want to specify a limit, you have to use a dedicated partition / mount point or a btrfs subvolume with quotas.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to make cron job to clean up unused docker images, unused docker volume, and exited docker container. I use this method myself.